# What's the meaning of 時間のやり方 in a sentence

Tags: expressions

What's a reasonable translation to the following sentence, particularly this expression: **時間のやり方**

> そういう時間の配分、そういう**時間のやり方**が多い、ということですね。普通ということです。

From the above sentence, this is what I get, but it does not make much sense:

> "There are many time distributions, and **many ways to make time**. It is normal."

For contextualization, I took the sentence from this [text](https://p14.zdusercontent.com/attachment/479934/f8WoEjVwPC1iXFJjDnDmi9DCI?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..kRJLMLTowE-B_JxeP7CBRQ.G4m0qNgU4EVpi9u1EHDei4SUyr6CmQ0XdfPaM99iJHzfDs3gXul-qkJYFbn8WWpxo8jB9T0pUFOVYGdSMsGUxqg8pTKxbU0xhksfzoCSWnCFOT9gjT2ms0YWmj3BNGjfyzcxfe9rto-bUXRIae2wNFTe-f-PWDZ97do83WN0VNRru59CmWkOcQ6KoI7mHKzUGo8l8RFuI2UYXlt-d1Mueukgfo0HU7bWPcz3MpWvxXkkXh_P9KmoMyggzJOAo4hslG-kklMBlwkatOlpUeb96Q.2nMCBTiIqTjBSWOCxoDUmA), take a look at the last sentence from the first page.

Comment: They meant 時間の使い方, maybe? "A way of using/spending time"

Comment: Though not 100% necessary, a little more context might help one answer this question more confidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means more like **many ways to spend time** or **many ways to pass time**, but I admit that it does say it in weird way in japanese too. 
How about **many ways to do time**? Does it make sense??

Comment: I believe **many ways to spend time** fits better. Thank you!